# Redirecting to the correct localization: Nginx, Apache, memcached and Django

Tags: django, localization, memcached, nginx, mod-python

My site is localized using a string in the URL (e.g. `/DE/certificate` gets the German version, `/US/certificate` gets `en-US`, etc.) For some URLs on the site, leaving out the localization part redirects to a best-guess (usually `/US/<url>`) but for others I just get a blank page.

This is a Django site. Django is running through `mod_python` on Apache, listening on port 8000. Nginx is on port 80. When a request comes in, Nginx checks memcached for the page, and if it's in the cache, serves directly from the cache. If memcached misses, Nginx proxies the request back to Apache. Django stores the output of most `GET` requests into memcached. Traffic is very spiky for this site, and this method helps us get the most from a relatively low-powered server.

The problem described above is **not** present if I skip Nginx and the cache, and send requests directly to Apache on port 8000. This leads me to suspect the problem is in the Nginx/memcached layer.

Watching Apache's log on a successful request shows a 302 being returned for the unlocalized request, and a new request for the corrected URL. Watching Nginx's log for a failed request shows a 200 response, and an apparently empty response. My hunch is that an empty page is being stored in memcached. Is there any way to investigate the keys in memcached to confirm this hunch, or should I be looking for some other information to debug the problem?

Here's the relevant section of the nginx configuration:

```
    location / {
             if ($request_method = POST) {
                proxy_pass http://production;
                break;
             }
             default_type "text/html; charset=utf-8";
             set $memcached_key "/key-$uri";
             memcached_pass     localhost:11211;
             error_page 404 502 = /django;
    }

    location = /django {
             proxy_pass http://production;
             break;
    }
```

Would it help for me to include my Django caching middleware? I set it up following [this article](http://soyrex.com/articles/django-nginx-memcached) pretty much exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use "@django" (on both lines) instead of "/django"

Comment: Bingo, just what I needed. I also needed to remove the "=" from the location line (so it's `location @django {` ). Detailed in the documentation if I'd known where to look: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page